# Ruby 'inline' 3.12 array return?

Tags: c++, ruby, inline

How to return an array from C code in Ruby?
I'm use Inline v3.12.

```
require 'inline'
class Object
inline(:C) do |builder|
  builder.c "
    VALUE some_method(VALUE s) {
      int s_len = RARRAY_LEN(s);
      int result = 0;
      int i = 0;

      VALUE *s_arr = RARRAY_PTR(s);

      for(i = 0; i < s_len; i++) {
        result += NUM2INT(s_arr[i]); 
      }

      return rb_float_new(result); // HERE I NEED ARRAY RETURN !!!!!
    }"
    end
end

a = Object.some_method([1,2,3,4])
puts a
```

- List item
- List item
- List item
- List item

Comment: Omg, does *all* your code look like this?

Comment: Why would one do something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: 
rb_ary_new4(long length, VALUE *values") - 
Returns a new Array of the given length and populated with the C array values.

It's taken from here: http://rubycentral.com/pickaxe/ext_ruby.html
(part Commonly Used Methods)